# Not able to access spark log of hadoop cluster from my local machine

Tags: azure, hadoop, port, azureportal

I've set a Hadoop cluster in Azure and it hs its won security group and a network.
When I tried to check the exception behind few submitted spark jobs, could not see those (via browser) from my local machine giving "This site can’t be reached" exception. 
URL I'm trying to reach:
http://MACHINE_XXXXX:19888/jobhistory/logs/MACHINE_YYYYY:45454/container_e11_1463399230026_0304_01_000001/container_e11_1463399230026_0304_01_000001/usewr123

There is a windows machine within same network. I can access the URL from that machine (using remote desktop) without any problem.

Then I added port  19888 and 45454 to inbound security rule of the security group. But my problem is not resolved.

Why I'm not able access the URL from outside of the network?

Any help would be highly appreciated.